# How do you link a HTML img to toggle between hiding/showing an element (in this case, a table) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My apologies if the question is poorly written and hard to understand (I'm just starting to code & new to stackoverflow :) ), but I would like to be able to click on each image and have different tables pop up for each planet with facts (Mercury table example is shown in picture). I have the table where I'd like it to show up, but not sure how to link it to each img, and replace it with a different table associated with the new planet when selected (hoping this makes sense!).

I don't have any code yet for js but I'm guessing I'll need a separate function for each image?

Also, how do you put space (padding I think?) between the html images?

So many questions, my bad!

```css
h1 {
  color: seagreen
}
h4 {
  color: seagreen
}
table {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 67%;
}
td {
border: 2px solid black;
text-align: left;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 1ex
}
th {
border: 3px solid black;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 1ex
}
mercury {
  
}
```

```html
<h1>The Eight Planets</h1>
<h4> Click on any planet below to learn!</h4>
<!-- mercury -->
<img id = "mercury"
src="https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcGFjZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzAwMy8wOTcvb3JpZ2luYWwvaWcyOTVfcGxhbmV0c19NZXJjdXJ5XzAyLmpwZw=="
width="100" height="100">
<table>
<tr>
  <th> PLANET PROFILE</th>
  <th>QUICK FACTS</th>
  </tr>
  <td> Moons: 0 </td>
  <td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td>
  </tr>
  <td> Diameter: 4,879km </td>
  <td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td>
  </tr>
<td> Orbit period: 88 days </td>
<td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td>
</tr>
<td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td>
<td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td>
</tr>
<td> First record: 14th century BC </td>
<td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td>
<!-- venus -->
<img id = "venus"
     src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/98/09/66/9809666c323d35c266117428dd495791.jpg" 
width="100" height="100">
<!-- earth -->
<img id = "earth" src="https://3c1703fe8d.site.internapcdn.net/newman/gfx/news/hires/2014/1-earth.jpg"
width="100" height="100">
<!-- mars --> 
<img id = "mars" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg"
width="100" height="100">
<!-- jupiter -->
<img id = "jupiter" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg/330px-Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<!-- saturn --> 
<img id = "saturn" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/planet-saturn-vector-vector-id165060389?k=6&m=165060389&s=612x612&w=0&h=wfA9UIF6EaoGannx6fiE1gSe3G1ixtpGEfvXH2Eqhrg=" 
width="100" height="100">
<!-- uranus -->
<img id = "uranus" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Uranus2.jpg" 
width="100" height="100">
<!-- neptune -->
<img id = "neptune" src="https://img.purch.com/h/1000/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcGFjZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzAwMC8xMjIvb3JpZ2luYWwvMDcwOTE4X25lcHR1bmVfMDIuanBn" 
width="100" height="100">
</html>
```

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). For this case, you have to add a `table` element with an `id` attribute; use javascript for (un)hide the tables. I'll try make a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made small changes in the `Id` of your images, but basically:

- I added a `arr_planets` array which contains the name of the planets.
- Using javascript, loop the `arr_planets` array and check if the `id` of the selected `img` is the same as the one stored in the array.

This is just one example you can use for guide yourself:

```js
// Array with planets.
var arr_planets = ["mercury", "venus", "earth", "mars", "jupiter", "saturn", "uranus", "neptune"];

/* Show the selected div according to "id_planet_id" value */
function showTable(id_planet_id) {
  // Loop "arr_planets" array and check if it's the same as the supplied in the paramenter:
  for (var i = 0; i < arr_planets.length; i++) {
    // If so, show it.
    if (arr_planets[i] == id_planet_id) {  document.getElementById(arr_planets[i]).removeAttribute("style");
    } else {
      // Otherwise, hide them.
      document.getElementById(arr_planets[i]).setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: seagreen
}

h4 {
  color: seagreen
}

table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 67%;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 1ex
}

th {
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 1ex
}

mercury {}
```

```html
<h1>The Eight Planets</h1>
<h4> Click on any planet below to learn!</h4>
<div id="divPlanets" class="divContAllPlanets">
  <!-- mercury -->
  <img id="mercury_img" src="https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcGFjZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzAwMy8wOTcvb3JpZ2luYWwvaWcyOTVfcGxhbmV0c19NZXJjdXJ5XzAyLmpwZw==" width="100" height="100" onclick="showTable('mercury');" />
  <!-- venus -->
  <img id="venus_img" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/98/09/66/9809666c323d35c266117428dd495791.jpg" width="100" height="100" onclick="showTable('venus');" />
  <!-- earth -->
  <img id="earth_img" src="https://3c1703fe8d.site.internapcdn.net/newman/gfx/news/hires/2014/1-earth.jpg" width="100" height="100" onclick="showTable('earth');" />
  <!-- mars -->
  <img id="mars_img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg" width="100" height="100" onclick="showTable('mars');" />
  <!-- jupiter -->
  <img id="jupiter_img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg/330px-Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg" width="100" height="100" onclick="showTable('jupiter');" />
  <!-- saturn -->
  <img id="saturn_img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/planet-saturn-vector-vector-id165060389?k=6&m=165060389&s=612x612&w=0&h=wfA9UIF6EaoGannx6fiE1gSe3G1ixtpGEfvXH2Eqhrg=" width="100" height="100" onclick="showTable('saturn');" />
  <!-- uranus -->
  <img id="uranus_img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Uranus2.jpg" width="100" height="100" onclick="showTable('uranus');" />
  <!-- neptune -->
  <img id="neptune_img" src="https://img.purch.com/h/1000/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcGFjZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzAwMC8xMjIvb3JpZ2luYWwvMDcwOTE4X25lcHR1bmVfMDIuanBn" width="100" height="100" onclick="showTable('neptune');" />
</div>
<div id="divTablesPlanets">
  <div id="mercury" style="display: none;">
    <i>Add here your "mercury" table.</i>
  </div>
  <div id="venus" style="display: none;">
    <i>Add here your "venus" table.</i>
  </div>
  <div id="earth" style="display: none;">
    <i>Add here your "earth" table.</i>
  </div>
  <div id="mars" style="display: none;">
    <i>Add here your "mars" table.</i>
  </div>
  <div id="jupiter" style="display: none;">
    <i>Add here your "jupiter" table.</i>
  </div>
  <div id="saturn" style="display: none;">
    <i>Add here your "saturn" table.</i>
  </div>
  <div id="uranus" style="display: none;">
    <i>Add here your "uranus" table.</i>
  </div>
  <div id="neptune" style="display: none;">
    <i>Add here your "neptune" table.</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste, I hope this helps - change the planet details for each planet on the case of every planet.

```
 <style>
            h1, h4 {
            color: seagreen
            }

            table {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 67%;
            }

            td {
            border: 2px solid black;
            text-align: left;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            padding: 1ex
            }

            th {
            border: 3px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            padding: 1ex
            }

            /*    spacing for you images*/
            img {
            margin: 10px 5px;
            }
            </style>
            <div align="center">
            <h1>The Eight Planets</h1>
            <!--    I hope you like this joke here, click to see-->
            <h4 onclick="myPlanet('wakanda');"> Click on any planet below to learn!</h4>
            <!-- mercury -->
            <img onclick="myPlanet('mercury');"
            src="https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcGFjZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzAwMy8wOTcvb3JpZ2luYWwvaWcyOTVfcGxhbmV0c19NZXJjdXJ5XzAyLmpwZw=="
            width="100" height="100">
            <!-- venus -->
            <img onclick="myPlanet('venus');"
            src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/98/09/66/9809666c323d35c266117428dd495791.jpg"
            width="100" height="100">
            <!-- earth -->
            <img onclick="myPlanet('earth');"
            src="https://3c1703fe8d.site.internapcdn.net/newman/gfx/news/hires/2014/1-earth.jpg"
            width="100" height="100">
            <!-- mars -->
            <img onclick="myPlanet('mars');"
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg"
            width="100" height="100">
            <!-- jupiter -->
            <img onclick="myPlanet('jupiter');"
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg/330px-Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg"
            width="100" height="100">
            <!-- saturn -->
            <img onclick="myPlanet('saturn');"
            src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/planet-saturn-vector-vector-id165060389?k=6&m=165060389&s=612x612&w=0&h=wfA9UIF6EaoGannx6fiE1gSe3G1ixtpGEfvXH2Eqhrg="
            width="100" height="100">
            <!-- uranus -->
            <img onclick="myPlanet('uranus');" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Uranus2.jpg"
            width="100" height="100">
            <!-- neptune -->
            <img onclick="myPlanet('neptune');"
            src="https://img.purch.com/h/1000/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zcGFjZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzAwMC8xMjIvb3JpZ2luYWwvMDcwOTE4X25lcHR1bmVfMDIuanBn"
            width="100" height="100">
            <table id="planetInfo">
            </table>
            </div>

            <script>
            //    for starters this will do, practice more and you will get better
            function myPlanet(planet) {
            var info = "";
            var planetInfo = document.getElementById("planetInfo");
            switch (planet) {
            case "mercury":
            info += "<tr><th> MERCURY PLANET PROFILE</th><th>QUICK FACTS</th></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Moons: 0 </td><td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Diameter: 4,879km </td><td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Orbit period: 88 days </td><td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td><td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> First record: 14th century BC </td><td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td></tr>";
            break;
            case "venus":
            info += "<tr><th> VENUS PLANET PROFILE</th><th>QUICK FACTS</th></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Moons: 0 </td><td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Diameter: 4,879km </td><td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Orbit period: 88 days </td><td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td><td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> First record: 14th century BC </td><td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td></tr>";
            break;
            case "earth":
            info += "<tr><th> EARTH PLANET PROFILE</th><th>QUICK FACTS</th></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Moons: 0 </td><td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Diameter: 4,879km </td><td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Orbit period: 88 days </td><td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td><td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> First record: 14th century BC </td><td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td></tr>";
            break;
            case "mars":
            info += "<tr><th> MARS PLANET PROFILE</th><th>QUICK FACTS</th></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Moons: 0 </td><td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Diameter: 4,879km </td><td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Orbit period: 88 days </td><td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td><td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> First record: 14th century BC </td><td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td></tr>";
            break;
            case "jupiter":
            info += "<tr><th> JUPITER PLANET PROFILE</th><th>QUICK FACTS</th></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Moons: 0 </td><td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Diameter: 4,879km </td><td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Orbit period: 88 days </td><td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td><td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> First record: 14th century BC </td><td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td></tr>";
            break;
            case "saturn":
            info += "<tr><th> SATURN PLANET PROFILE</th><th>QUICK FACTS</th></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Moons: 0 </td><td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Diameter: 4,879km </td><td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Orbit period: 88 days </td><td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td><td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> First record: 14th century BC </td><td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td></tr>";
            break;
            case "uranus":
            info += "<tr><th> URANUS PLANET PROFILE</th><th>QUICK FACTS</th></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Moons: 0 </td><td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Diameter: 4,879km </td><td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Orbit period: 88 days </td><td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td><td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> First record: 14th century BC </td><td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td></tr>";
            break;
            case "neptune":
            info += "<tr><th> NEPTUNE PLANET PROFILE</th><th>QUICK FACTS</th></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Moons: 0 </td><td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Diameter: 4,879km </td><td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Orbit period: 88 days </td><td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td><td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> First record: 14th century BC </td><td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td></tr>";
            break;
            default:
            info += "<tr><th> WAKANDA PLANET PROFILE</th><th>QUICK FACTS</th></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Moons: 0 </td><td> Your weight on Mercury would be 38% of your weight on Earth </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Diameter: 4,879km </td><td> A day on the surface of Mercury lasts 176 Earth days </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Orbit period: 88 days </td><td> Mercury has more craters and impact marks that any other planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> Surface temperature: -173 to 427°C </td><td> After the Earth, Mercury is the second densest planet </td></tr>";
            info += "<tr><td> First record: 14th century BC </td><td> The orbit of Mercury is an ellipse rather than circular </td></tr>";
            }
            planetInfo.innerHTML = info;

            }


            </script>
```